# Why MongoDB local.oplog.rs collection has no index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

My MongoDB 4.4.8 local db:

[image]

While it will frequently make `$gt` queries on timestamp

[image]

How can I create index on this collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

local.oplog.rs is the [Replica Set Oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/)

That is a special-purpose system collection, the documents do not have an _id field, and no indexes are created or permitted on that collection.

It is a capped collection, and documents are always read in insertion order, so an index wouldn't be much help.